# How to expand/collapse bookmark options in winnovative html to pdf converter

Tags: asp.net, pdf, winnovative

I am using wnvhtmconvert to convert my html to pdf. I need to add expand/collapse bookmark function in my pdf.Could anyone please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to execute the ***this.bookmarkRoot.open=true;*** AcroJS script when the document is opened. You can find a complete example with source code for executing an AcroJS code when a PDF document is opened in a viewer in [Execute Acrobat JavaScript Code when Document is Opened demo](http://www.winnovative-software.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/PDF_Actions/Execute_JavaScript_Open_Action.aspx). The relevent code copied from that demo is:

```
protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    Document pdfDocument = null;
    try
    {
        // Convert a HTML page to a PDF document object
        pdfDocument = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToPdfDocumentObject(urlTextBox.Text);

        string javaScript = null;
        if (alertMessageRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            // JavaScript to display an alert mesage 
            javaScript = "this.bookmarkRoot.open=true;";
        }
        else if (printDialogRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            // JavaScript to open the print dialog
            javaScript = "print()";
        }
        else if (zoomLevelRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            // JavaScript to set an initial zoom level 
            javaScript = String.Format("zoom={0}", int.Parse(zoomLevelTextBox.Text));
        }

        // Set the JavaScript action
        pdfDocument.OpenAction.Action = new PdfActionJavaScript(javaScript);

        // Save the PDF document in a memory buffer
        byte[] outPdfBuffer = pdfDocument.Save();

        // Send the PDF as response to browser

        // Set response content type
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=Execute_Acrobat_JavaScript.pdf; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

        // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
        Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

        // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
        Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the PDF document
        if (pdfDocument != null)
            pdfDocument.Close();
    }
}
```